# Failed to create object: error for Sonata_admin in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I get a very strange error when trying to create a new user using UserBundle with sonata-admin :

```
Failed to create object: App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

with this error too when creating a new User :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fos_user_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, created_at, updated_at, date_of_birth, firstname, lastname, website, biography, gender, locale, timezone, phone, facebook_uid, facebook_name, facebook_data, twitter_uid, twitter_name, twitter_data, gplus_uid, gplus_name, gplus_data, token, two_step_code, city, address, zip, country, function, session_id, licenca) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["sfdfsd", "sfdfsd", "sadffd@fssfd.fr", "sadffd@fssfd.fr", 0, "Hc1M4ls2NO1i6TsJQk5nEffjHRgmZ\/1nVuqbApYp0p4", "nNzAyKrAZ1B+wpflIHRzvTQkOx8\/W\/2BYGqW19lwuTJnTW4bWlMAH+\/Q\/zmTL8HzXYAZ47h0RP28d3Vtia9bMg==", null, null, null, "a:0:{}", "2023-11-14 16:20:27", "2023-11-14 16:20:27", null, "sdasadf", "asffds", null, null, "u", "hr", null, "sdafsd", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "sadfds", "sdffds", "dffd", null, "sadffdsa", null, null]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function, session_id, licenca) VALUES ('sfdfsd', 'sfdfsd', 'sadffd@fssfd.fr', 's' at line 1
```

I stack there now for few hours with no solution?

Comment: `function` is a sql keyword, you may want to rename it or use backticks to escape it, https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words